# In mongodb Which is better to use- MapReduce or Aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation

Some blogs says that mapreduce is slower than aggregation. So which one is ideal to use?

Comment: It _is_ slower. None is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)  you can clearly see it written:

For most aggregation operations, the *Aggregation Pipeline provides better performance* and more coherent interface. However, map-reduce operations provide some flexibility that is not presently available in the aggregation pipeline.